# Redirect in custom AsyncControllerActionInvoker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I want to intercept an action call and have created my own `AsyncControllerActionInvoker` where I test if the action has a certain attribute.

If so I want to cancel the action invokation and instead return a `RedirectResult`.

I can do this by overriding `InvokeActionMethod`, but that only works for regular actions. For async actions I have to override `BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters`.

What can I return from that method to return my `RedirectResult`? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can achieve what I want by implementing an `IAuthorizationFilter`.